# My Pi is not getting Internet even though he is on the same switch as my PC, which is getting internet

Tags: networking

So I have only one LAN-Socket in my room, so I have a cable running into a switch, connecting it with my PC and my Raspberry Pi b+. Now, most of the time, I only use this to ssh into the Pi from my PC, but now I need to install some software on the Pi, and it doesn't get internet connection. Ping to google fails (temporary error in name resolution (or something along the lines, it is in another language)), I can't add the gateway (I got by running ipconfig on my PC) to the pi using

> sudo route add default gw [address of the router]

> (RTNETLINK answers: Network is unreachable)

Can you guys help me?

Edit: picture of route -n:
[image]

Comment: Can you ping the router/gateway? Does `route -n` show the gateway?

Comment: ping gives 'destination host unreachable', i'll post a picture of route -n

Comment: the gateway address on my PC is different in the third place (the .100.)

Comment: So the gateway address differs? How do you expect reaching the internet if you define a bad gateway? Can you ping the gateway?

Comment: I cannot, gives destination host unreachable. so how can I define a good gateway?

Comment: Is you pi on a different subnet than the PC? What are their IPs? From where does the Pi get its IP?

Comment: same subnet, 2.195 and 100.3. Dont know where it gets it IP from, might be part of the problem

Comment: With a netmask of 255.255.255.0 (or /24) it is not the same subnet if the third octet is different.

Comment: so how do i fix that?

Comment: Do you have control of your router? Where does the "wrong" IP of the pi come from? Either set it manually with `ip`-command or it is set statically on the pi without your knowledge - check in e.g. `/etc/network/interfaces`.

Comment: I'll try it tomorrow, thank you for your help

Comment: How many cables are plugged into the switch? Two or three or more? What is connected at  its other sides beside RasPi and PC? By the way, please don't post pictures of text. Instead copy the text direct into the question: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/5014688).

Comment: ah, sorry, never posted before so i didn't know this. It's the cable running to my router, a cable running to my PC and one to my Pi. Nothing else.

Comment: manually changing the IP adress in /etc/network/interfaces did the trick! Thank you all for the help!

Comment: Please create an answer for the solution and mark it as the accepted one after two days with a click on the tick on its left side. Only accepting an answer will finish the question. That prevents it from being shown as an unsolved Post to the community and saves them/us a lot of work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have an ordinary answer, the questioner answered his question in a comment:

> manually changing the IP adress in `/etc/network/interfaces` did the trick! Thank you all for the help!